# karma init there is no file matching pattern *Spec.ts

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, ionic2, karma-jasmine

I try to config unit test in Ionic 2 app,
I follow http://lathonez.github.io/2017/ionic-2-unit-testing/

when I try to lunch my unit test with karma

```
karma init karma.conf.js
```

and follow the steps, I have error: `There is no file matching this pattern`
Pattern : *spec.ts